# "I engaged in" or "I was engaged in"

Tags: american-english

Is it right to say

> "I engaged in some research projects".

or should I say

> "I was engaged in some research projects".

Comment: I'd prefer saying: I *got* engaged in... However, "I engaged in ...." does not look correct to me!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Looks to me that both examples given would be acceptable, but have slightly different meanings. The former means you took some action, the latter describes a condition in which you took action. Choose the version which best suits your feeling of the situation.

Answer (score 0):

First sentence is incomplete. Some words in between may change the meaning.

Like

a) I got engaged in....
b) I engaged myself in ......etc.

For me it is correct to say,

1) "I am engaged in some research projects."

It is present Tense giving idea about your present state/situation.

2) "I was engaged in some research projects".

it is purely past tense gives idea about your past state/Situation.